# What are objective benefits and drawbacks of read.csv() versus read_csv()?

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is a more conceptual question, but in class today, I was told by my professor that it would be preferable to use `read_csv` rather than `read.csv`. For more context, we are working with [tidyverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidyverse) in this class.

As such, since `read_csv` and `read.csv` (as far as I'm aware) both read [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) files, what are the objective benefits and drawbacks of using one function versus the other?

Comment: I prefer `data.table::fread`

Comment: read.csv() coerces strings to factors :-(

Comment: unless you use the `as.is = TRUE` argument.

Comment: There are multiple criteria and they conflict.  These includes minimizing dependencies, consistency with rest of program (does it use base or tidyverse) and performance.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418412)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`read_csv` is significantly faster for large .csv files. See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/12/reading-csv-files-in-r-readcsv-vs.html) for more information. Personally, I pretty much always use `read_csv` by default.

Comment: I would cast some doubt on those blog results. They conflict with the official tidyverse / readr site for starters - "*[readr is] slower (currently ~1.2-2x slower. If you want absolutely the best performance, use data.table::fread().*" - https://readr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: @thelatemail You're correct; the cited blog is now two years old and at the very least is out of date.  `fread` (as of version 1.11) automatically uses parallel processing. In every experiment I've run, on a variety of file sizes,`read.csv` is slowest, `read_csv` is 2-3x faster, and `fread` is 2-3x faster again.